# Why does < instead of << in stream output still compile?

Tags: c++, implicit-conversion, ostream

Today I made a small typo in my program, and was wandering why I wasn't getting any output, although the program compiled fine. Basically it reduces to this:

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::cout < "test"; // no << but <
}
```

I have absolutely no idea what kind of implicit conversion is performed here so the program still compiles (both g++4.9.2 and even g++5). I just realized that clang++ rejects the code. Is there a conversion to `void*` being performed (cannot think of anything else)? I remember seeing something like this, but I thought it was addressed in g++5, but this doesn't seem to be the case.

**EDIT:** I was not compiling with `-std=c++11`, so the code was valid in pre-C++11 (due to conversion to `void*` of `ostream`). When compiling with `-std=c++11` g++5 rejects the code, g++4.9 still accepts it.

Comment: I get a warning from g++ 4.9.2 about an unused computed value though when using `-Wall` though.

Comment: @Raphael indeed, when I compiled I didn't look at all warnings, now I see and realized what happened, although gotta say it is a bit unusual. I use most of the time `-Wall`, however this was a tiny piece of code that I compiled in sublime text and realized it magically works

Comment: Why [this](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/667a9c3ad1ee9afe) gives 0 as an output ?

Comment: @Destructor Because you end up comparing 2 pointers: `(void*)std::cout` with a string literal decayed to a `const char` pointer, and the comparison seem to be false. See the answers to understand why the conversion.

Comment: @vsoftco: pointer comparison of this type is unspecified behavior according to C++ standard. See [this](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/5a657b96dd59eed8)

Comment: @Destructor Yes I know, you asked why and I told you. The compiler can do whatever it wants.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, the compiler is converting `cout` to a `void*`. If you use the `-S` switch to get the code's disassembly, you'll see something like this:

```
    mov edi, OFFSET FLAT:std::cout+8
    call    std::basic_ios<char, std::char_traits<char> >::operator void*() const
    cmp rax, OFFSET FLAT:.LC0
    setb    al
    test    al, al
```

Which makes it clear that `operator void*` is the culprit.

Contrary to what Bill Lynch said, I'm able to reproduce it with `—std=c++11` on [Compiler Explorer](http://goo.gl/RgweWS). However, it does appear to be an implementation defect, since C++11 should have replaced `operator void*` with `operator bool` on `basic_ios`.

Comment: In c++11, there is no `operator void *()` on `std::ostream`. So that would be an implementation defect.

Comment: I think it is a defect in g++4.9 (g++5 rejects it)

Comment: g++ 4.9 **isn't** fully C++11 compliant in some points to not break it's ABI. This is one of the things. g++ 5 will be fully C++11 compliant.

Comment: Yes, I just double-checked that this was changed in C++11.

Answer (score 5):

This is only valid before C++11.

You're basically doing: `((void *) std::cout) < ((char *) "test")`

Comment: sorry, I take it back, was not using `-std=c++11`.... g++5 rejects it indeed, g++4.9.2 doesn't, even with `-std=c++11`.