# misplaced < instead of << in cout in C++

Tags: c++, c++11, g++, constants, cout

This is a follow up question to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5665221/typo-with-cout-myint-why-does-it-work/5665324?noredirect=1#comment51650872_5665324). In response to my comment [@Johannes Schuab - litb](https://stackoverflow.com/users/34509/johannes-schaub-litb) request me to ask this question.

This is the program:

```
#include <iostream>
int main()
{
    int const income = 0;
    std::cout << "I'm sorry, your income is: " < income;
}
```

This is my comment on that post:

> This will also fail in compilation on g++. How can you say that it
>   compiles in GCC? Yes, but the program in ur question compiles fine on
>   MSVS 2010.? I am using g++ 4.8.1 & it gives me so many errors when I
>   write < instead of << by mistake. Looks like older GCC allows this,
>   but they should give any warnings or strictly compiler errors.

I tried it on gcc 5.2.0 & surprisingly it compiles fine. (See live demo here http://goo.gl/QwGNs9). I also tried it on clang 3.6. It compiles with warnings. (See live demo [here](http://goo.gl/WQBYAF)). But on my computer I am using Orwell Dev C++ & it uses g++ 4.8.1. When I tried the same program on that compiler, it gives me so many compilation errors. I tried it on g++ 4.9.2 & it still compiles fine giving warning :

`right operand of comma operator has no effect [-Wunused-value]`

But when I explicitly compile like following on g++ 4.9.2:

```
g++ -std=c++11 -o test test.cpp

g++ -std=c++14 -o test test.cpp
```

It gives me too many compilation errors. I also tried it on online C++ compilers that support C++14 (See live demo [here](http://ideone.com/1tO2hK)). But when I compile program in C++03 mode like following on g++ 4.9.2

```
g++ -std=c++03 -o test test.cpp
```

It compiles fine.

So, my questions are:

1) Why different versions of g++ compilers behave differently when compiling this program? Is this bug in gcc/g++ compilers?

2) Is this C++03 issue that has been fixed in C++11?

3) When I remove the **const** keyword from the program & compile it, program  fails in compilation. Why? Why removing **const** keyword leads to compilation errors?

Comment: One question per question please. Also please include relevant source code, so that the question can be read and understood without referring to other pages.

Comment: @Downvoters: Who downvoted? Why downvotes?

Comment: Who voted to close? What's wrong in question?

Comment: Please ask self-sufficient questions. People don't like following links just to understand your question.

Comment: See also this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29723423/why-does-instead-of-in-stream-output-still-compile

Comment: @PaulR: Ok, i've added source code.

Comment: @vsoftco: why removing const keyword leads to compilation error?

Comment: @PravasiMeet that's probably some kind of weird gcc compiler bug, cannot find any other reasons. My compiler (clang 3.5) compiles it without `const`.

Comment: @PravasiMeet If you specifically call out the warning flags then it will warn/error in 5.2 http://goo.gl/PTiXrX